# How do I move a table to the left side of the text in r markdown?

Tags: r, markdown

compiling to PDF.
My table is not a sophisticated table made with a function, just a simple markdown table. is it possible to make it inlined (to the left) with the text?

```
    |    | Fant | astic |
|----|------|-------|
| 1  | yes  | no    |
| 2  | no   | no    |
| 3  | yes  | no    |
| 4  | yes  | no    |
| 5  | yes  | no    |
| 6  | yes  | no    |
| 7  | yes  | no    |
| 8  | yes  | no    |
| 9  | yes  | no    |
| 10 | yes  | no    |
| 11 | yes  | no    |
| 12 | yes  | no    |
| 13 | yes  | no    |
| 14 | yes  | no    |
| 15 | yes  | no    |
| 16 | yes  | no    |
| 17 | yes  | no    |
| 18 | yes  | no    |
| 19 | yes  | no    |
| 20 | yes  | no    |

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
```

[from this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2af4.png)

[to hopefully this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF2Ee.png)

Comment: Are you compiling to PDF or HTML or something else?

Comment: compiling to PDF

Comment: Check this out--you need to use LaTex: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LaTeX**-solution

```
\begin{minipage}[h]{0,7\textwidth}

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 

TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText 

\end{minipage}
\hspace{2.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0,3\textwidth}

|    | Fant | astic |\\
|----|------|-------|\\
| 1  | yes  | no    |\\
| 2  | no   | no    |\\
| 3  | yes  | no    |\\
| 4  | yes  | no    |\\
| 5  | yes  | no    |\\
| 6  | yes  | no    |\\
| 7  | yes  | no    |\\
| 8  | yes  | no    |\\
| 9  | yes  | no    |\\
| 10 | yes  | no    |\\
| 11 | yes  | no    |\\
| 12 | yes  | no    |\\
| 13 | yes  | no    |\\
| 14 | yes  | no    |\\
| 15 | yes  | no    |\\
| 16 | yes  | no    |\\
| 17 | yes  | no    |\\
| 18 | yes  | no    |\\
| 19 | yes  | no    |\\
| 20 | yes  | no    |\\

\end{minipage}
```

[image]

For the precious adjusting you can use **vjust** and **hjust** and some other [options](https://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-minipage.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in my `huxtable` package:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "David Hugh-Jones"
date: "30/11/2021"
output: pdf_document
---

## Some text

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit etc.

```{r table, echo = FALSE}
library(huxtable)
head(mtcars, 3) |> 
      as_hux() |>
      set_position("wrapright")
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
````

[image: right-aligned table]

You will have to build the table in R manually, but that looks pretty easy:

```r
hux(Fant = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", etc.), Astic = rep("No", 15))
```